# How to include a file in an online server from localhost and access the functions?

Tags: php, xampp

I have a file called config file containing lots of function in my online server, I decide to include this file on a project I'm doing locally by simply coding

```
<?php include("http://example.com/config.php") ;?>
```

And I have a function called

```
<?php restrict(){
//content
} ;?>
```

This function is not working despite the fact that I've included the file

Answer (score 0):

You certainly don't have included the source code of the PHP file but the ouput it does, it won't work. You have a webserver like apache or nginx + fpm that interprets the source code you have exposed.

You can serve this file as it without any interpretaion (by disabling `mod_php` on apache for instance) **but you shouldn't**. Exposing the source code is always a bad idea and must be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

To allow inclusion of remote files, the directive [allow_url_include](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-include) must be set to On in php.ini

But that is a security problem, that's why is generally disabled (I've never seen it enabled, actually)